# export excel using angular 10 with rowspan, colspan with pagination

Tags: angular-material, angular10, mat-table-exporter

How to export an excel in angular 10 with mat export excel.

in my table have row span and col span with pagination, i am using mat export excel it is working but when i have rowspan or colspan the table is not exported properly.